# Why am I geting this table not found error? "object ___ does not exist"

Tags: sql

I'm trying to run the following query. It was working fine until i added the column gpv.i_val

the error i'm receiving is "object gpv does not exist" when clearly it does. I'm assuming this is something simple but can't seem to place my finger on it.

```
             SELECT 
             gpv.i_val,
             gcv.i_pln,
             gcv.c_typ_cov,
             gcv.d_eff,
             gcv.d_eff_pln,
             gcv.c_sta,
            gcv.d_sta,
            gcv.c_mde_bft_fst,
            gcv.a_bft_fst,
            gcv.c_mde_bft_sec,
             gcv.a_bft_sec,
            gcv.c_mde_bft_trd,
             gcv.a_bft_trd,
             gcv.p_cre_hom,
             gcv.c_cl_rsk,
             gpv.c_val,
             gcv.c_pol


            FROM Pearl_P.tltc906_gcv gcv,
             pearl_p.tltc912_gpv gpv

              WHERE  gcv.i_pln > 0
            AND gcv.i_pln = gpv.i_pln
            and gcv.c_pol between 'lac100001' and 'lac100004'

         UNION

             SELECT
            gpv.i_val,
             gcv.i_pln,
             gcv.c_typ_cov,
             gcv.d_eff,
             gcv.d_eff_pln,
             gcv.c_sta,
             gcv.d_sta,
             gcv.c_mde_bft_fst,
             gcv.a_bft_fst,
             gcv.c_mde_bft_sec,
             gcv.a_bft_sec,
             gcv.c_mde_bft_trd,
             gcv.a_bft_trd,
             gcv.p_cre_hom,
             gcv.c_cl_rsk,
             gcv.c_pol,
             ''
        FROM Pearl_P.tltc906_gcv gcv

            where NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM pearl_p.tltc906_gcv gcv,
             pearl_p.tltc912_gpv gpv

            WHERE  gcv.i_pln > 0
            AND gcv.i_pln = gpv.i_pln
            )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second select in the UNION references GPV, but the table itself is not included?

```
 SELECT gpv.i_val,
        ....
        ....
             ''
        FROM Pearl_P.tltc906_gcv gcv
        WHERE ....
```

Answer (score 1):

gpv does not exist in your unioned query.  you're first select item in that unioned query is gpv.i_val.  That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

gpv is not in the from clause in the second query in the union?